# ASP.NET CORE MVC CRUD operation. Create form doesn't work anymore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-3.0, razor-pages

Im am currently working on my CRUD operations for the website. On the attached pictures you can see that im using the create form for 2 purposes. 1. to create a user and 2 to edit a user. My Query is made well but when im adding a hidden id to get a certain user for editing. I cannot press create user anymore because i passed the piece of code in at picture 1. (the line i selected)

But when i remove this piece of code i can create a user but when im trying to edit a user when removing this piece of code it just edits the user and then creates a new one with the edited content. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

p.s. i made screenshots of the controller and the piece of code where it goes wrong.

Kind regards,

Sem

> [Piece of code where it goes wrong][1] [User controller][2] [User
> controller][3] [Data transfer objects][4] [CreateOrUpdate
> query/function][5]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XxDe.jpg   [2]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5pqh.jpg   [3]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vLXM.jpg   [4]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2OBn.jpg   [5]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADyv5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot you are calling same action method from UI, in that case you need to validate id in your action method to see if it valid then its update otherwise it will be add. Scenario first time your page loaded id will be empty and second time if you load then it will have id and same you can use for edit.

Hope this solve your problem

Comment: So I need to change some things in the controller?

Comment: @SemdeWilde yes

Comment: Should I be able to fix the issue by validating the id on the Create action method that I only made to show the form?

Comment: @SemdeWilde yes since you are using same form for both purpose.

Comment: Follow this article , https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/crud-operations-in-mvc. It will help you

Answer (score 0):

First, you can copy your code using '**{}**' in above toolbar, so it will be more convenient for others to test your code.

> but when im trying to edit a user when removing this piece of code it just edits the user and then creates a new one with the edited content.

You can check the database for the passed model, if id exists, create one, but if not, remove the old one and create this new one.

Here is a demo with linq, you can check the logic and modify my code to yours:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessCreate(UsersDto user)
    {
        if (!_context.UsersDtos.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id))  //if not exist, create one directly
        {
            _context.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else {               //else, delete old one and create new one       
            var therow = _context.UsersDtos.Where(x => x.Id == user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            _context.Remove(therow);
            _context.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }          
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

In Create.cshtml,you can show the id:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="ProcessCreate">
<div class="form-group" hidden>
    <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="First_name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="First_name" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="First_name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
//.......
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="CreateOrEdit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any problems with my post? If you have question, feel free to ask. And if it can help, you can [set it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it can help more people.